# How can i get the Previous Volume Value after Soundset Command - Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

How can i get the Previous Volume Value after Soundset Command?

I want to run a Sound with a Volume Value and then go back to the Orginal (Previous) Volume Value.

The Code that i have does not goes back.

```
SoundSet 70
SoundPlay C:\Windows\media\tada.wav,wait
```

Answer (score 1):

**This plays a sound at 70% volume and then restores the original volume**

```
SoundGet oldvolume
soundset 70
SoundPlay C:\Windows\media\tada.wav,wait 
soundset oldvolume
```

**Reference**

- Documentation for [SoundGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGet.htm)
- Documentation for [SoundGetWaveVolume](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGetWaveVolume.htm)

Comment: Hi, @JimU - i did try it out on my Windows 10 system and i had Set the Volume on value 50 but it does not goes back to Previous value 50 -  it goes back to value 31 (30,351782%) - MsgBox %oldvolume%` - is it maybe possible that it can calculate back to the exact value 50. (soundset 50)

Comment: @Guser17 If you Replace **SoundGetWaveVolume oldvolume** into **SoundGet oldvolume** - This Will Goes back to the Previous Value 50 (soundset 50)

Comment: @stevecody - I did change the Command line and it works. thanks.